# Is there a better way to get the fully qualified URL of a controller without the action part?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need the fully qualified URL of my controller for constructing URLs in Javascript. I do not, however want a specific action, since that will change depending on client side code.
I tried (in my _Layout.cshtml)

```
Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Foo" })
```

However, this will invariably also give me the action for the current view, e.g. "/Foo/Bar". 
Of course, I could now throw away the last slash and everything after, but it seems to me there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: This will depend on the routes you have set. If you throw away the action, which action do you expect to get called? In your routes do you have some convention about the action name?

Comment: @Darin The action names come from data-attributes in my HTML. I have some JS that takes the controller-URL and appends the action name. The URL as generated in my View will never be used directly.

Comment: I'm not sure, I clearly understand what you want to reach. Do you want to have route "Foo" instead "/Foo/Bar" for "Bar" action? If i'm wrong please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. You can set the action name explicitly to an empty string:

```
Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Foo", action = "" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Request.Url.Host + Url.Action("Index", "Foo");
```

It'll automatically drop the action part when it generates the URL.

Comment: This works, but it relies on "Index" being the default action in the route, since MVC will drop default parts of a route. That is not particularly obvious, especially for later maintainers of the code. Still, +1 for a workaround :)

Comment: Cheers, I'll mark this as a favourite and give your solution a try next time I need to do something similar again.